# django: access url name pattern in cbv

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I would like to map several urls to the same view.

```
url(r'^foo/', BaseView.as_view(), name='foo'),
url(r'^bar/', BaseView.as_view(), name='bar'),
url(r'^buzz/', BaseView.as_view(), name='buzz'),
```

Is there anyway in my class based view I can access the name parameters? I know it's possible to specify it in `as_view()`. But is there a way around that extra boilerplate code?

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
url(r'^/(?P<name>[-\w]+)/$', BaseView.as_view())
```

Then you can just grab the name from BaseView:

```
name = self.kwargs['name']
```

Comment: Then the template url resolvers won't get set. Unless I do that somehow in the view.

Comment: I'm not sure why the resolvers wouldn't get set using the RE, but they would otherwise. Are you sure?